# Duplicate all columns except for some of them

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Is there an option to duplicate row in sql server without write all the columns? I just want to write the columns that I want to insert it by myself.

for example:

MYTABLE:

```
Id|Name|Status|Date
-------------------
2|abca|active|03.10
```

so I can do:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (Id, Name, Status, Date )
SELECT NEWID(), "bird", status, Date
  FROM MYTABLE 
 WHERE Id = "2"
```

it will duplicate the row:

```
Id  |Name|Status|Date
-------------------
2   |abca|active|03.10
fg35|bird|active|03.10
```

can't I duplicate all columns, except for what I write?

in this example:
something like (pseudo code):

duplicate all columns in MYTABLE where Id="2" except for (id="newID()", name="bird")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in SQL Server you either need to provide all values for all columns:

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES(value1, value2, ...)
```

or provide the columns you want to insert to

```
INSERT INTO TableName (column1, column2, ...) VALUES(value1, value2, ...)
```

You cannot achieve what you want in a general sense.

There may be a way to do it in some specific cases buy duplicating all columns and updating some but that will depend on your ability to distinguish the newly inserted row from the previously existing one.